# MVC core Select list populated after Ajax call with model binding

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, selectlist

At first this seemed such an easy task but now a few hours later I still haven't figured this out.

The first GET of AddProduct would only populate the ProductCategories, when an item in this list is clicked the SetSubCats functionion gets called and an ID is passed to the AddProduct controller method. This is setting the SubCats select list. I can see them being populated in my locals whilst debugging.

The last step would just be to update the options of this select, without refreshing the page (which would send a 0 as ID to controller). Seems trival, yet the solution is alluding me. I guess I'm not handling the return of the server correctly. I've found answers to just use jquery to populate the select but I want to keep modelbinding.

Much obliged for any assistance.

//Controller:

```
public IActionResult AddProduct(int ID)
        {
            AddProductVM model = new AddProductVM();
            model.ProductCategories = new SelectList(productService.GetAllProductCategories(), "ID", "Name");
            model.SubCategories = new SelectList(productService.getSubCatsByMainCatID(ID), "ID", "Name");
            return View(model);
        }
```

//The selects of the view:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="badge-light" asp-for="ProductCategories">@Localizer["Product category"]</label>
        @if (Model.ProductCategories != null)
        {
            <select size="@Model.ProductCategories.Count()" class="form-control slctCat" asp-for="Product.Category" asp-items="@Model.ProductCategories">
            </select>
        }
        <span class="text-info">@Localizer["Select the main category this product belongs to"]</span>
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.Category)</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group" >
        <label class="badge-light" asp-for="SubCategories">@Localizer["Product sub category"]</label>
        @if (Model.SubCategories != null)
        {
            <select size="@Model.SubCategories.Count()" class="form-control" id="slctSubCats" asp-for="Product.SubCategory" asp-items="@Model.SubCategories">
            </select>
        }
        <span class="text-info hide">@Localizer["Select the sub category this product belongs to"]</span>
        <span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.SubCategory)</span>
    </fieldset>
```

//Ajax call:

```
const SetSubCats = (e) => {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
    var ID = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ShopkeeperDashboard/AddProduct',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { ID: ID },
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {

        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
            //What to do here so only the #slctSubCats gets loaded? 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create a partial view that includes all your selects,
for example "_Selects.cshtml"

in your main view you to replace your select html by partial view:

```
<div id="selects">
 <partial name="_Selects" />
</div>
```

after this you have to return partial view from the action you are calling in AJax:

```
public IActionResult GetSelects(int ID)
        {
            var model = new AddProductVM();
            model.ProductCategories = new SelectList(productService.GetAllProductCategories(), "ID", "Name");
            model.SubCategories = new SelectList(productService.getSubCatsByMainCatID(ID), "ID", "Name");
            return PartialView("_Selects",model);
        }
```

And your ajax:

```
const SetSubCats = (e) => {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
    var ID = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ShopkeeperDashboard/GetSelects/'+ID,
        type: "GET",
    
        success: function (result, status, jqXHR) {

          $("#selects").html(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {

        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
            //What to do here so only the #slctSubCats gets loaded? 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the hint of partial view Sergey!

Final code:

//Reserving empty fieldset in the form

```
<fieldset class="form-group" id="selectSubCats"></fieldset>
```

//Method called by Ajax returning partialView

```
public IActionResult SetSubCats(int ID)
        {
            IEnumerable<SubCategories> subCats = productService.getSubCatsByMainCatID(ID);
            AddProductVM model = new AddProductVM();
            model.SubCategories = new SelectList(subCats, "ID", "Name");
            return PartialView("_SelectedSubCats", model);
        }
```

//And most important actualy using the return result of the call

```
const SetSubCats = (e) => {
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).val());
    var ID = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ShopkeeperDashboard/SetSubCats',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { ID: ID },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#selectSubCats').html(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {

        },
        complete: function (result) {            
        }
    });    
}
```